# Removing an element while using multiple iterators on a Java HashSet

Tags: java, iterator, set, hashset

I am trying to update a set of Sets based on sharing one or more common elements, when two elements have a (or more) common element, they will be combined to a single element and so on.

For example:

Input: `{{1,2}, {3,4,5}, {2,4}, {7,8}}`

Output should be: `{{1,2,3,4,5}, {7,8}}`

Input: `{{1, 2}, {5, 8, 9}, {3, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 7}, {7, 8}}`

Output should be: `{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9}}`

Here is my Java implementation,

```
   static boolean hasCommon(HashSet<Integer> s1, HashSet<Integer> s2)
   {
      for (Integer i : s1)
      {
         if (s2.contains(i))
            return true;
      }
      return false;
   }

   static HashSet<HashSet<Integer>> updateElements(HashSet<HashSet<Integer>> newSetofSets)
   {
      Iterator<HashSet<Integer>> it = newSetofSets.iterator();

      while (it.hasNext())
      {
         HashSet<Integer> s1 = it.next();

         Iterator<HashSet<Integer>> it2 = it;

         while (it2.hasNext())
         {
            HashSet<Integer> s2 = it2.next();

            System.out.println("s1 = " + s1.toString() + ", s2 = " + s2.toString());
            System.out.println(newSetofSets.toString());

            if (hasCommon(s1, s2))
            {
               for (Integer i : s2)
               {
                  s1.add(i);
               }

               it2.remove(); // remove s2 after adding its elements to s1.
               System.out.println(newSetofSets.toString());
            }
         }
         System.out.println(newSetofSets.toString());
      }

      return newSetofSets;
   }
```

For the input: `[[1, 2], [5, 8, 9], [3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 7], [7, 8]]`

I'm getting,

```
[[1, 2, 4, 7, 8], [5, 8, 9], [3, 4, 5]]
```

The first iterator `it` doesn't move to next element after `it2` finished.

Any help to solve this problem will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's good to remember that adding/removing items from the collection that you're looping over is not good practice.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but it should have some solution. i need to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You only have one iterator in your code. When you execute the following code:

```
Iterator<HashSet<Integer>> it2 = it;
```

You are expecting that an new iterator `it2` is created that continues at the position where `it` left off. This is not the case. What you are doing is creating a new variable that is pointing to the same iterator. This is called 'Pass-by-Reference'.

So now you have 2 variables pointing at the same iterator. When you use `it2.next()` it is the same as saying `it.next()`. When the second while loop is completed the iterator is at the end of the list and `it.hasNext()` will be false because `it2.hasNext()` is the same as `it.hasNext()`.

Comment: So, I found the problem, now I have to find a way out of here.